# LoadError: cannot load such file -- commons-math-2.2.jar

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use this gem: [Statsample, short blog post about using it](http://sciruby.com/blog/2013/11/07/statistics-with-ruby-time-series-and-general-linear-models/)

Here is a quick way to reproduce the error (using ruby 2.3.1p112)

```
gem install statsample
gem install statsample-timeseries
irb
require 'statsample-timeseries'
```

Result:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- commons-math-2.2.jar
```

I've tried installing some additional gems/libs but they don't make the error go away.

```
gem install sciruby-full
apt-get install libcommons-math-java
```

It's not clear what I'm missing. Do I need to `apt-get` a certain library? Why is it trying to load a jar?

Comment: Are you using ruby or jruby?

Comment: Ruby since I'm using `irb`, but I've tried it with `jirb` too and I get the same result.